# mysql where condition question

Tags: php, mysql

is that possible to use WHERE like this;

```
$no = $_GET['no'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `myno` - $no = 4";
...
```

if not, how can i get the rows like the below example ?

EDIT: 
to be more clear,

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `dates` WHERE date - $today = 7";
```

i want to find rows that has date field which is 7 days ago

thx

Comment: What does it say when you try it.

Comment: Also that there is some serious security deficiency. Putting a get variable directly in an sql query is a huge nono.

Comment: actually i cant try it now, i just wanted to ask, i will try when i am on my own computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the field is a date field

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `myno` = DATE_SUB(`myno`, INTERVAL 7 DAY)"
```

**Edit:** or I would prefere this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), `myno`) = 7"
```

[Take a look at the date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate)

Comment: these looks what i am looking for, but why you prefer 2. one ?

Comment: Just because it's less to write ^^, And a bit easies to read :)

Comment: oh i tried but it didnt work with that "WHERE date_added >= DATE_SUB(`$dt`, INTERVAL 7 DAY) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,8"

Answer (score 2):

You can do all sorts of expressions in a `WHERE` clause, but be careful: if you do

```
SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE myno - ? = 4
```

it'll not be able to use any indexes, whereas:

```
SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE myno = 4 + ?
```

will be able to use an index on myno.

Comment: Yep, The same principle applies ... use the form where you're comparing the variable to a constant expression, rather than comparing a variable expression to a constant.  That way indices will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `myno` = 4  + $no"
```

Comment: but it is different from my purpose

Answer (score 0):

$weekAgo = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 week"));

$query = "SELECT * FROM `numbers` WHERE `myno` = '$weekAgo';

Comment: Why use PHP to figure out the time when MySQL have excellent functions for this?

Comment: Why use MySQL to figure out the time when PHP has excellent functions for this?

1. It seems that the creator did not have a thorough understanding of MySQL, so I provided an alternative PHP answer.

2. If he is gonna check multiple times, you won't need MySQL to figure out the date multiple times, it is already stored in the variable.